# Aligning left edges of a fluid width div and static width divs

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align left edges of static width divs and a fluid one as it is shown in the illustration below?

Left edges of all divs should be aligned on all resolutions and "div b" should occupy all the space to the right.

[image: div]

EDIT:
Roko C. Buljan's answer solves the puzzle. For the browsers without calc or vw unit support, I believe Modernizr and pollyfills will come to rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with a bit of calculations using `calc()` and `vw` unit (*ViewportWidth*)

### Using a 500px common container: [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/futabu/1/edit)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background:#ECD06B;
  color:#fff;
}
#container{
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.static, .fluidtoright{
  padding:50px 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.static{
  background:#E9561C;
}
.fluidtoright{
  background:#5981E4;
  width: calc((100vw / 2) + 250px); /* 250 is half the 500 width */
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    
    <div class="static"></div>
    <div class="fluidtoright">text aligned right just to test</div>
    <div class="static"></div>
    
  </div>
```

### Without using a 500px container: [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/futabu/2/edit)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background:#ECD06B;
  color:#fff;
}
.static, .fluidtoright{
  padding:50px 0;
  
}
.static{
  margin: 15px auto;
  width:500px;
  background:#E9561C;
}
.fluidtoright{
  background:#5981E4;
  margin-left: calc((100vw / 2) - 250px);
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
    <div class="static"></div>
    <div class="fluidtoright">textaligned right to test</div>
    <div class="static"></div>
```